# Overflow on CPU, but not GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, precision

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
x = torch.ones(1000000).half()

print(x.mean())
print(x.cuda().mean())
```

```
tensor(nan, dtype=torch.float16)
tensor(1., device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
```

Why?

Comment: Overflow because you convert to float16? Overflow either during the conversion, or when the mean is computed.  As for why the GPU didn't find NaN: it either had a nicer distribution, or ignored the overflow.

Comment: ... well, since it found a mean of 0.7, it probably ignored the overflow. The mean should be a lot closer to zero!

Comment: You should directly rand with the correct dtype: `randn(..., dtype=float16) ` to avoid those accidents.

Comment: @Demi-Lune "nicer distribution" it's the same input? I don't follow "ignored", and the `to` isn't relevant.

Comment: Well, you drastically changed your test case since my last comment :-( . By nicer distribution, I mean that the random generator could generate a number bigger that the float16 limit (which is only 65519, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations ).   But on second thoughts, it can't be during the conversion to_float16, because it would put an inf or nan in the input array for the gpu.

Comment: @Demi-Lune The code is identical in context of the question, I refactored it to avoid unrelated guesswork.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting [wikipedia's float16 entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations):

> 65519 is the largest number that will round to a finite number (65504), 65520 and larger will round to infinity. This is for round-to-even, other rounding strategies will change this cutoff.

The CPU version is triggering an overflow when computing the mean (it is probably summing all values, then dividing by their number).
The GPU version works correctly (well, it seems to work on the ones, it didn't on the random distribution you provided in your first version of the question), maybe it starts by dividing all values by the size of the tensor, then adds them up?

Interestingly, [np.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) specifically documents that float16 need special attention:

> By default, float16 results are computed using float32 intermediates for extra precision.

If you run your test with np instead or torch, it works fine on CPU.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question nor state anything I didn't already know. There is a definitive answer which should be known by those familiar with torch's CUDA-side implementation.

Comment: _"it didn't on the random distribution you provided in your first version of the question"_  - it did.

Comment: It **didn't** raise an error, but the result was **obviously** wrong: 0.7 cannot be the mean of a random normal distribution.

Comment: `abs(randn)` ⠀⠀